# Redux how actions are passed to particular reducer

Tags: redux

I am having decent understanding of Redux.

One thing I wonder is in a large application there will be multiple actions and reducers.

My question is

- When an action is dispatched how it finds the appropriate reducer ?
- Could there be duplicate actions in reducer ?
- How modified state data is passed back from reducer to component ?

Even when I look at redux flow I do not understand these questions

Please clear my confusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**When an action is dispatched how it finds the appropriate reducer?**

When an action is dispatched, and if you are using combine reducers, all the reducers will be triggered. The appropriate state change happens in the tree where action.TYPE matches the dispatched action.TYPE.

**Could there be duplicate actions in reducer?**

Let's think of a chat application. Lets say when there's a new message coming in and there are two stores called messageStore and unreadStore. And there's an action called NEW_MESSAGE. All two stores will update on receiving new messages.

```
message = (state=[], action) ->
  switch action.type
    when NEW_MESSAGE
      state # new state

unread = (state=[], action) ->
  switch action.type
    when NEW_MESSAGE
      state # new state

combineReducer {message, unread}
```

In the same reducer, you can dispatch same action twice but it is unnecessary. In different reducers, you can do it as mentioned.

**How modified state data is passed back from reducer to component?**

1. Your global-store is passed down into components through provider. As per redux documentation, the `<Provider />` makes the Redux store available to any nested components that have been wrapped in the `connect()` function.

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
const store = createStore(combineReducer(message, unread));
<Provider store={store}>
   <App />
</Provider>
```

2. Once the global-store is passed down to the components nested inside it, you make use of `connect()` to connect the normal react component to redux store. The functions and the global store state variables are then passed as props into the component. Every time they change in global store, they are passed into all the connected components.

```
class ReduxEmpl extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div>I'm connected</div>
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({ messages: state.message.messages })
const dispatchToProps = dispatch => ({ functionToDispatch: (params) => dispatch(functionToDispatch(params));

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ReduxEmpl);
```

Hope I solved your confusion :)

Answer (score 2):

**1. When an action is dispatched how it finds the appropriate reducer?**

All actions pass through all reducers and middlewares in your application, that's why you have a switch statement to handle if a certain reducer will handle certain action.

**2. Could there be duplicate actions in reducer ?**

You can dispatch an action and handle this action in multiple reducers as you want.

**3. How modified state data is passed back from reducer to component ?**

When you connect a component with redux through `connect` HOC, you are subscribing your component to the store and the way the store works is when it changes it notifies the components subscribed, then mapStateToProps is executed and generates new data for the components, if the data has changed the component will get updated otherwise it won't.

I hope it helps you, if you have any doubt please let me know.